# Connection hangs infinitely when trying with OpenSSL to RabbitMQ - no error mentioned

Tags: ssl, openssl, rabbitmq

I've configured SSL connection in a RabbitMQ server.

When looking into Rabbit logs - I clearly see that Rabbit listens to 5671 port:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::15:27:59 ===
started SSL Listener on [::]:5671

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Dec-2017::15:27:59 ===
started SSL Listener on 0.0.0.0:5671
```

Unfortunately, when trying to open connection with OpenSSL:

```
openssl s_client -connect myrabbitserver.com:5671 -cert client/cert.pem -key client/key.pem -CAfile testca/cacert.pem
```

I'm getting this response immediately:

```
CONNECTED(00000178)
```

And that's it. Client just hangs.
I've tried to set a connection timeout on RabbitMQ server - but it won't help as I don't get any further details regarding any problems.

When I look into RabbitMQ logs - I don't see any request went in.

Any help ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Use TLS 1.0 (or above) and [Server Name Indication (SNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things has been working out for me.
I'm using windows so I need to use "\" instead of "\" in rabbit config file.

In addition, it's important to notice policy errors and ignore some of them if you need

Comment: Thank you for following up here.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me. Connection is achieved but there are no cert exchange. Reason is that cert cannot be loaded, either for a wrong passphrase of the key or wrong permissions in directory/files (cert, key and chained cert).

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me recently in RabbitMQ 3.7.10, and the cause was that the key I was referencing was password-protected, but I had failed to provide the password in the RabbitMQ config, like this:

```
ssl_options.password = password
```

Unfortunately there was absolutely nothing in the RabbitMQ logs about this, even with the log level set to debug.